# Using micro cd's in a MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

Is there a proper way to insert micro cd's so they are less likely to get stuck inside the cd slot on my MacBook pro?

Answer (score 3):

Your MacBook Pro User Guide will state the following:

```
Slot-loading SuperDrive
This optical drive reads and writes standard-size CDs and DVDs.
```

By standard-size CDs and DVDs it means that the slot-loading drive is not designed to take mini/micro optical discs of any sort.

Instead, you will need an external tray-loading optical drive or access to an older Mac with one. Of course, if it's some sort of promotional material, software, etc, then you may be able to view/download it from the internet.